# AWS Glue Bookmark produces duplicates

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, parquet, aws-glue

I am submitting a Python script (pyspark actually) to a Glue Job to process parquet files and extract some analytics from this data source.

These parquet files live on an S3 folder and continuously increase with new data. I was happy with the logic of bookmarking provided by AWS Glue because it helps a lot: basically allows us to process only new data without reprocessing already processed data.

Unfortunately in this scenario I notice instead that each time duplicates are produced and looks like that AWS Glue bookmarking is not working at all. What's the reason of this unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html

> The Apache Parquet and ORC formats are currently not supported.

**UPDATE**

Since [Jul 26 2019](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/07/aws-glue-now-provides-ability-to-bookmark-parquet-and-orc-files-using-glue-etl-jobs/) AWS Glue supports Parquet and ORC formats as well for bookmarking

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check now. It supports Parquet and ORC. But Version 1.0 and later. Version Version 0.9, it was not supporting

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html